# how to make banner image full width HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to make my banner image the full-screen width, but I have had no success. Here are my codes.

```css
* {
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 2000px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header-image {
  background-image: url("idb.jpg");
  margin-top: 20px;
  top: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  color: black;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 400px;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="topa">
    <a class="menu-text" href='./home.html'>Home</a>
    <a class="menu-text" href="./start-a-project.html">Start</a>
    <a class="menu-text" href='./say-hi.html'>Say hi</a>
  </div>
</header>
<br>
<br>
<section class="header-image">
  <div class="header-image-text">
    <h1>Hero Image.
      <p>Text Text Text</p>
    </h1>
  </div>
</section>
```

[image: The visual representation]

Comment: Make the `header` and the `topa`  div `width: 100%` and also make the `topa` div a flex with `justify-content: end;`

Comment: Can I see the code of how this should look? I am still stuck.

Comment: Yes, they are directly under the body. I have <body> then <header> and so on. If the <body> tag is affecting it. What's the fix?

Comment: I missed that you're setting margin:0; on all the elements, so body should not be affecting it. Ignore my last comment. I deleted it because of the very reason. I have posted an answer, I couldn't really reproduce what the issue is, or maybe I didn't understand. You can have a look and respond accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Make the `header` and the `topa` div `width: 100%` and also make the `topa` div a flex with `justify-content: end;`

And I think you meant to write `body{...}` not `*{...}`. `*` apply the style to every element

```css
body {
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 2000px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header-image {
  background-image: url("idb.jpg");
  margin-top: 20px;
  top: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  color: black;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 400px;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
}
header,.topa{
  width:100%;
}

.topa{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: end;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="topa">
    <a class="menu-text" href='./home.html'>Home</a>
    <a class="menu-text" href="./start-a-project.html">Start</a>
    <a class="menu-text" href='./say-hi.html'>Say hi</a>
  </div>
</header>
<br>
<br>
<section class="header-image">
  <div class="header-image-text">
    <h1>Hero Image.
      <p>Text Text Text</p>
    </h1>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to make sure the image takes up the whole width, do I understand your problem correctly? If yes, I just took a random image online and used the html and css that you've and it appears to work fine. The image takes up the full width. Maybe something wrong with your image? Maybe you can post a problematic code snippet that has the image as well?

```css
* {
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 2000px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header-image {
  background-image: url("https://www.gannett-cdn.com/-mm-/05e97d16e7fb53439a4222e53dcba47d4d31dde8/c=0-97-1280-584/local/-/media/USATODAY/USATODAY/2014/06/04/1401911998000-AP-Color-Cosmos.jpg?width=3200&height=1680&fit=crop");
  margin-top: 20px;
  top: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  color: black;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 400px;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="topa">
    <a class="menu-text" href='./home.html'>Home</a>
    <a class="menu-text" href="./start-a-project.html">Start</a>
    <a class="menu-text" href='./say-hi.html'>Say hi</a>
  </div>
</header>
<br>
<br>
<section class="header-image">
  <div class="header-image-text">
    <h1>Hero Image.
      <p>Text Text Text</p>
    </h1>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I have used fixed it via help from ATP, it works as it should now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML code in the question remains the same. Here is the working CSS code

```css
body{
    background: hsl(240, 50%, 5%);
    color: #fff;
    padding: 25px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    min-width: 300px;
    max-width: 2000px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
```

[Final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hxr2A.png)